# Spring Jackson array instead of List

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-restcontroller

In my Spring Boot application I have a following `@RestController` method:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}/decisions/{childDecisionId}/characteristics/{characteristicId}/values", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ValueResponse create(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long decisionId, @PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long childDecisionId, @PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long characteristicId,
        @Valid @RequestBody CreateValueRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
        ....
         request.getValue()
        ...
    }
```

This is my `CreateValueRequest`  DTO:

```
public class CreateValueRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1741284079320130378L;

    @NotNull
    private Object value;

...

}
```

The value can be for example `String`, `Integer`, `Double` and the corresponding arrays like `String[]`, `Integer[]`.. etc

In case of `String`, `Integer`, `Double` everything is working fine and I'm getting a correct type in my controller method. But when I send an array in my controller method I'm getting `List` instead of array.

Is it possible (and if so - how ) to configure Spring + Jackson in order to get array (only in this particular case) instead of `List` for `request.getValue()`

Comment: i guess you have to use a custom Jackson serializer/deserializer in order to process your json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Jackson configuration that does that is `USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY` and you can read about it [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features#type-conversions). It will create an `Object[]` instead of a `List` for an `Object` field in the POJO you are deserializing into. An example using this config:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY);
```

The documentation for Spring Boot [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) describes how to configure the `ObjectMapper` that Spring Boot uses. Basically you have to set this environment property in the pertinent properties file:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.use_java_array_for_json_array=true
```